# error C2864: 'Generator::ci' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class

Tags: c++

Hi i´m trying to compile a app with VistualStudio 2008, but these errors are being displayed:

```
Error   2   error C2864: 'Generator::ci' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class    f:\virtualdub\roslogoaway\dehaze\file\main.cpp  99  dehaze
Error   3   error C2864: 'Generator::c' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class f:\virtualdub\roslogoaway\dehaze\file\main.cpp  100 dehaze
Error   8   error C2679: binary '-=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'cv::Vec<_Tp,cn>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  f:\virtualdub\roslogoaway\dehaze\file\main.cpp  340 dehaze
```

The part of the code that generated those error are:

```
template <class ForwardIterator,class Generator>
void generate(ForwardIterator first,ForwardIterator last,Generator g)
{
    while(first!=last)
{
    *first++ = g();
}
```

}

```
struct Generator
{
    Generator():ci(0.0){}
    Generator(float c_init):c(c_init){}
    float operator()(){ci+=c;return ci;}
    float operator()(float c_init){c=c_init;return c;}
    float ci=0.0;
    float c=0.0;
};
```

(...)

```
cv::Mat dehaze(cv::Mat& image,cv::Mat& difference,cv::Point ale,int k,int rho,double xi)
{
 cv::Mat output = cv::Mat(image.rows,image.cols,image.type());
 float c = 1.0/k;
 vector<float> ci(k);
 std::generate(ci.begin(),ci.end(),Generator(c));

 vector<cv::Mat> layers;
 vector<cv::Mat> mask_layers;
 vector<cv::Mat> diff_layers;
 Vec3f ale_temp= image.at<cv::Vec3f>(ale);

 for(int i=0;i<ci.size();i++)
 {
     cv::Mat layer=image.clone();

     layer-=(ci[i]*ale_temp); <------ here
```

I have no idea how to fix that. Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The first two errors are about your in-class initialization of `ci` and `c`. This is a C++11 feature and is only supported by Visual C++ 2015 and up. You'll have to initialize them in the constructor:

```
struct Generator
{
    Generator():ci(0.0), c(0.0f) {}
    Generator(float c_init):ci(0.0), c(c_init){}
    float operator()(){ci+=c;return ci;}
    float operator()(float c_init){c=c_init;return c;}
    float ci;
    float c;
};
```

The third error is unrelated. You're trying to subtract a `cv::Vec3f` from a `cv::Mat`, which doesn't make any sense. I have no idea what you're trying to do here, so I can't help much more than that.

By the way, Visual C++ 2008 is *old*.